# Concise way of writing conditional method chaining

Tags: python

Is there a more concise way to write something like the following in Python?

```
if c:
  x = obj.method_1()
         .method_2()
         .method_3()
else:
  x = obj.method_1()
         .method_3()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
x = obj.method_1()
if c:
    x = x.method_2()
x = x.method_3()
```

Answer (score 0):

This saves you some characters (a single `x =` and two colons `:`) but it's way harder to read than your initial code.

```py
x = obj.method_1().method_2().method_3() if c else obj.method_1().method_3()
```

You could, however, add some line continuation characters `\` to split it up a bit (which basically adds the 4 characters we saved "saved" back in):

```py
x = \
  obj.method_1().method_2().method_3() \
if c \
else \
  obj.method_1().method_3()
```